# 12 months sale and max of them in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have one query to find out `Material wise`and`Month wise` data from `salesdata table`

Sample

I can find below data

```
MaterialNo  Jan   Feb   Mar   Apr   May   Jun   Jul  Aug  Sep  Oct  Nov  Dec  
1           10    15    20    30    40    45    56   85   100  95   42   32   
2           12    20    86    32    45    42    62   74   86   42   84   62
3           15    20    46    54    46    42    19   0    62   75   94   98
```

I want Last Two columns (MaxSale, MaxSaleMonth) in SQL SERVER 2008 R2

```
MaterialNo  Jan   Feb   Mar   Apr   May   Jun   Jul  Aug  Sep  Oct  Nov  Dec  MaxSale   MaxSaleMonth
1           10    15    20    30    40    45    56   85   100  95   42   32   100       Sep
2           12    20    86    32    45    42    62   74   86   42   84   62   86        Mar
3           15    20    46    54    46    42    19   0    62   75   94   98   98        Dec
```

Please Suggest me easiest solution.

my Current Query is as below

```
Select 
MaterialNo,
SUM(CASE WHEN CAST(SalesData.dSalesDate AS DATE) BETWEEN '01-Jan-2015' AND  '31-Jan-2015' THEN SalesData.iQty  ELSE 0 END) AS [Jan],
SUM(CASE WHEN CAST(SalesData.dSalesDate AS DATE) BETWEEN '01-Feb-2015' AND  '28-Feb-2015' THEN SalesData.iQty  ELSE 0 END) AS [Feb],
SUM(CASE WHEN CAST(SalesData.dSalesDate AS DATE) BETWEEN '01-Mar-2015' AND  '31-Mar-2015' THEN SalesData.iQty  ELSE 0 END) AS [Mar],
SUM(CASE WHEN CAST(SalesData.dSalesDate AS DATE) BETWEEN '01-Apr-2015' AND  '30-Apr-2015' THEN SalesData.iQty  ELSE 0 END) AS [Apr]
From SalesData
Group By
MaterialNo
```

Comment: Please post you query. Suggestion: create subqueries to get the data you need.

Comment: i post my existing query

Comment: @Hirengardhariya I have updated my answer.  First you have to made a function and then use in your select query.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Pivot .. you can find the easiest way.

```
select max(month), row_max = max(val)
from yourtable
pivot
(
  salesmonth 
  for col in (C1, C2, C3, C4..c12)
) piv
group by id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query for your result. First create a function the use in the select query.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].GREATEST(@val1 int, @val2 int,@val3 int, @val4 int,@val5 int, @val6 int,@val7 int, @val8 int,@val9 int, @val10 int,@val11 int, @val12 int) returns int as begin
declare @intMax as int
set @intMax = @val1
if @val2 > @intMax
    set @intMax = @val2
if @val3 > @intMax
    set @intMax = @val3
if @val4 > @intMax
    set @intMax = @val4
if @val5 > @intMax
    set @intMax = @val5
if @val6 > @intMax
    set @intMax = @val6
if @val7 > @intMax
    set @intMax = @val7
if @val8 > @intMax
    set @intMax = @val8
if @val9 > @intMax
    set @intMax = @val9
if @val10 > @intMax
    set @intMax = @val10
if @val11 > @intMax
    set @intMax = @val11
if @val12 > @intMax
    set @intMax = @val12
return @intMax
end

SELECT MaterialNo, Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec , GREATEST(score1, score3, score3, score4) AS MaxSale   
CASE GREATEST(Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec) 
     WHEN Jan THEN 'Jan'
     WHEN Feb THEN 'Feb'
     WHEN Mar THEN 'Mar'
     WHEN Apr THEN 'Apr'
     WHEN May THEN 'May'
     WHEN Jun THEN 'Jun'
     WHEN Jul THEN 'Jul'
     WHEN Aug THEN 'Aug'
     WHEN Sep THEN 'Sep'
     WHEN Oct THEN 'Oct'
     WHEN Nov THEN 'Nov'
     WHEN Dec THEN 'Dec'
   END AS MaxSaleMonth
FROM salesdata
```

Comment: are  you sure `GREATEST()` is available in `SQL Server` ?

Comment: No GREATEST is not avliable in SQL Server but you can make a function with name GREATEST and then use You can write your login in your function. This is the simplest method you can get your result

Answer (score 0):

```
; with
cte as
(
    select  MaterialNo, 
            SalesMth    = month(dSalesDate),
            iQty        = sum(iQty)
    from    SalesData
    where   dSalesDate  >= '2015-01-01'
    and     dSalesDate  <  '2016-01-01'
    group by MaterialNo, month(dSalesDate)
)
select  MaterialNo, [1] as Jan, [2] as Feb, [3] as Mar, . . . . .
        iQty as MaxSales, SalesMth as MaxMth
from    cte c
    pivot
    (
        sum(iQty)
        for SalesMth in ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], . . .. )
    ) p
    outer apply
    (
        select  top 1 SalesMth, iQty 
        from    cte x
        where   x.MaterialNo    = MaterialNo
        order by iQty desc
    ) m
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help..

```
SELECT monthdata.MaterialNo,[Jan],[Feb],[Mar],[Apr],MaxSale,MaxSaleMonth
FROM (
Select 
MaterialNo,
SUM(CASE WHEN CAST(SalesData.dSalesDate AS DATE) BETWEEN '01-Jan-2015' AND  '31-Jan-2015' THEN SalesData.iQty  ELSE 0 END) AS [Jan],
SUM(CASE WHEN CAST(SalesData.dSalesDate AS DATE) BETWEEN '01-Feb-2015' AND  '28-Feb-2015' THEN SalesData.iQty  ELSE 0 END) AS [Feb],
SUM(CASE WHEN CAST(SalesData.dSalesDate AS DATE) BETWEEN '01-Mar-2015' AND  '31-Mar-2015' THEN SalesData.iQty  ELSE 0 END) AS [Mar],
SUM(CASE WHEN CAST(SalesData.dSalesDate AS DATE) BETWEEN '01-Apr-2015' AND  '30-Apr-2015' THEN SalesData.iQty  ELSE 0 END) AS [Apr]
From SalesData
Group By MaterialNo
)monthdata
INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT MaterialNo ,unitsSold AS MaxSale   
,mnt AS MaxSaleMonth
FROM (
SELECT  MaterialNo,ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY MaterialNo
ORDER BY SUM(iQty) DESC
)rowid,SUM(iQty) unitsSold
,DATENAME(MONTH,CAST(CAST (Month(dSalesDate) AS VARCHAR )+'/01/'+CAST(YEAR(dSalesDate)  AS VARCHAR )AS DATETIME)) AS mnt
FROM SalesData
WHERE  dSalesDate BETWEEN '01-Jan-2015'
AND '30-Apr-2015'
GROUP BY MaterialNo,Month(dSalesDate),YEAR(dSalesDate)
) a
WHERE rowid=1
)maxdata ON maxdata.MaterialNo=monthdata.MaterialNo
```